# OpenGL wrong viewport

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

I have a problem with rendering a triangle in 800x600 res window. I never called glViewport in my code, yet i have wrong results. Triangle renders only to lower half of the window.

I have tried to set viewport in my code by calling glViewport(0,0,800,1200) it fixes the problem temporarily but when i enter fullscreen everything is messed up again.

```
#include "ref.h"

int main(void){
    WindowInit(&window, "Test", WINW, WINH, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    game = GameInit(60);

    VAO vaodef = VAOInit(1);
    VAOCreate(&vaodef);
    VAOBind(&vaodef);

    const GLfloat triangle_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    Shader triangle_shader;
    LoadShader(&triangle_shader, "VertexShader.glsl", "FragmentShader.glsl");

    GLuint vertexArrayBuffer;
    int num_vertices = 3;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexArrayBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(triangle_data) / (sizeof(GLfloat) / 3)), triangle_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glUseProgram(triangle_shader.program);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glUseProgram(0);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window.window);
    SDL_Delay(5000);

    WindowDestroy(&window);
}
```

Results: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt6lb.png)

Comment: Where do you call `glViewport(0,0,800,1200)` on this program?

Comment: Well i tried i did not put that in my code here

Comment: You should create a [mcve]. Just showing your code like that does not help very much

Comment: It seems that when i "extract" opengl code from functions i can get my triangle perfectly fine.. Problem solved, minimal reproducible example is up there.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you not calling `glViewport`? It's an essential function that's setting up the drawing process. A lot of OpenGL beginners have the misconception that `glViewport` is some sort of initialization step, or in your case a specialization. It's not. *It's a drawing related function!*

The idiomatric way to drawing to a window with OpenGL begins with setting the viewport to the position and size wherein that window you want to draw, *at each and every iteration of the drawing loop*. Yes, it's idiomatic to call it repeatedly, since working with, say *framebuffer objects*, or drawing overlay elements, like HUDs, require the change the viewport multiple times throughout drawing a frame.

So the fix for your problem is to call `glViewport` with the size of the drawable region you want to draw to, right at the beginning of the drawing function.

Comment: I usually call it in on resize event of my window (along with setting of projection matrix due to possible change in aspect ratio), but if I use anything that is changing it then yes I need to call it in each frame ... some environments have problems with going into fullscreen not invoking on resize calls .. if the case its possible to scan the size change in some timer ...

Comment: Question is solved, the problem was vsize() macro. I just replaced it with sizeof() and everything works. Wrong number of bytes were alocated.